# how to shift total sum record to down so always new record can be created?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My question is what if my records are filled till fourth now i want to add fifth but how i manage total row it should shift automatically one down.
for example:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | $ 12 |
| Second | $ 12 |
| third |  |
| fourth |  |
| total | 24 |

further I want to keep showing total row even sheet scroll up or down.
anyone know how it can be done

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B2:"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1; 2)))
```